# Pickadate onset rendering new disabled times

Tags: javascript, jquery, render, pickadate

I'm trying to make 2 inputs - one with pickadate , other with pickatime. When user picks a date, array of disabled times is being passed to pickatime function. I have two arrays that are passed from backend with php. I am taking those and using for which times/dates are need to be disabled. My code:

```
        $('#myfield1').pickadate({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        //array with dates
        disable: exclude_days_real,
        //I want to render new pickatime every time I choose a new date
        onSet: function() {
            //check if there are disabled hours in a date user have chosen
            var chosen_date = $('#myfield1').val();
            var disabled_time_real = [];
            //if there are disabled hours, make them correct array from js object
            if (time_array[chosen_date]) {
                var disabled_time = time_array[chosen_date];
                for (i = 0; i < disabled_time.length; i++) {
                    var time = disabled_time[i];
                    var time_synt = time.split(':');
                    disabled_time_real.push(time_synt);
                }
            }
            //make time input field blank
            $('#myfield2').val('');
            //and here I think it should render time select every time date is set, but it works only one time
            $('#myfield2').pickatime({
                format: 'H:i',
                interval: 60,
                min: [10, 00],
                max: [16, 00],
                disable: disabled_time_real
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I make it to render every time user picks a new date ? I thought about removing input and inserting new one but I think it should have better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling .pickatime with options binds the pickatime to the input one time with those initial options.  Calling it again with different options does nothing, in my experience.  Instead you need to use the [picker API](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/), to get a handle to the picker API.  You can then use the API methods to change options that have already been set in the initializer.

I have modified your code to demonstrate.  I haven't tested it, but I have similar code in my app which works.

```
// save a reference to the pickatime object
var time_field = $('#myfield2').pickatime({
    format: 'H:i',
    interval: 60,
    min: [10, 00],
    max: [16, 00],
});

// get and save the 'picker' API object
var time_picker = time_field.pickatime('picker');

$('#myfield1').pickadate({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    //array with dates
    disable: exclude_days_real,
    //I want to render new pickatime every time I choose a new date
    onSet: function() {
        //check if there are disabled hours in a date user have chosen
        var chosen_date = $('#myfield1').val();
        var disabled_time_real = [];
        //if there are disabled hours, make them correct array from js object
        if (time_array[chosen_date]) {
            var disabled_time = time_array[chosen_date];
            for (i = 0; i < disabled_time.length; i++) {
                var time = disabled_time[i];
                var time_synt = time.split(':');
                disabled_time_real.push(time_synt);
            }
        }
        //make time input field blank
        $('#myfield2').val('');

        // reset previously disabled times, if any, through the picker API
        time_picker.set('enable', true);

        // set the new disabled times through the picker API
        time_picker.set('disable', disabled_time_real);
    }
});
```

See [the documentation](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable) for a full explanation.  The docs are excellent.

Comment: it is one big step forward, thanks! only now when I choose date with disabled hours and then another, those hours do not "undisable". and when I first choose date without disabled hours and then with disabled ones, I can see it renders good because there are disabled hours in a list

Comment: @PaulMark, I suggest reading the documentation.  http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable.  It explains that disabling dates adds to a collection of items; it does not replace them.  You'll need to re-enable all dates before resetting the disabled dates.  `time_picker.set('enable', true)`.  Answer updated (still untested).  I hope it works and that you accept it, but I highly encourage reading documentation anyway, to understand all of your options.  Amsul did an exceptional job documenting Pickadate, which you can take advantage of.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly. I looked at documentation, but didn't notice this. Now it makes sense. Thanks have a great life:)